# How to get two highest salary in emp table?

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

```
BREAK ON DEPTNO SKIP 1
compute sum of sal on deptno
 SELECT  deptno, empno, ename,sal FROM
  (SELECT  deptno, empno, ename, sal FROM emp )
  WHERE  EXISTS  (SELECT deptno  FROM dept)     order by 1,2 , sal desc ;
```

How can I get two highest sal from emp, and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: For one thing, your code is way too complicated for such a simple request.  Also, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Yes, but I need to sum sal of every deptno,  and than show only first and second highest salary, and if there is two salary with the same record, than I have to show three records ( 5000, 3000,3000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you want. In the title you say "two highest salary", but in the comment you mention something about a sum.

The following will show the two highest salaries. If there are multiple "highest" salaries, all will be shown

```
select deptno, empno, ename, sal
from (
  SELECT deptno, empno, ename, sal, 
         dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) as rnk
  FROM emp
) 
where rnk <= 2
order by sal desc;
```

To get this per department, you can use this:

```
select deptno, dept_salary
from (
  select deptno, dept_salary, 
         dense_rank() over (order by dept_salary desc) as rnk
  from (
    SELECT deptno, sum(sal) as dept_salary
    FROM emp
    group by deptno
  ) t1
) t2
where rnk <= 2
order by dept_salary desc
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want all rows with the two highest distinct salaries in each department, then use `dense_rank()` as follows:

```
select deptno, empno, ename, sal
from (select e.*, 
             dense_rank() over (partition by deptno, order by sal desc) as seqnum
      from emp e
     ) e
where seqnum <= 2
order by deptno, sal desc;
```

It looks like the question will be deleted, but it might as well have a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple query actually:

```
SELECT  deptno, empno, ename,sal FROM emp eb
WHERE (deptno, empno) IN
   (SELECT depno, empno FROM
       (SELECT deptno, empno FROM emp ei
           WHERE ei.deptno = eb.deptno
           ORDER BY ei.sal DESC
       ) WHERE rownum <= 2
    );
```

The last `WHERE rownum <=2` differ from SQL to SQL, in Mysql you would need `LIMIT 2`, in MSSQL Server, you would need to do `SELECT TOP 2`, in Oracle `WHERE rownum <= 2`. Depends on the engine you use.

Comment: The ANSI SQL way is `FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY`, supported by newer SQL Server and Oracle versions, amongst others,

Comment: Thank you, but now there isn't any record of deptno= 10. And other deptno 20 and 30 have just one record. This is my code now : BREAK ON DEPTNO SKIP 1
compute sum of sal on deptno
 SELECT  deptno, empno, ename,sal FROM emp
 WHERE rownum <= 2  order by sal desc;

Comment: @GoranBartBartolić : From the question it wasn't clear that you want per department. Updated.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I forgot. I have oracle SQL Developer, and I have to use where rownum <=2. Can you write me how can I than write this query? I have tried but there is an error. Thank you a lot for your time, I'm now with that